# Tracking file downloads from Dropbox

Tags: dropbox, orangedox

I was wondering if it is possible to track how many downloads were made from a file on my Dropbox.

I discovered the Orangedox app and it seems that it is possible to create a link and track these downloads.

My questions is: The only way to track the download is after creating this link in Orangedox, I mean, is not possible to track the downloads made previously to the creation of this link, is it? I would have to create the link through Orangedox and only after that, I can track the downloads, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

> The only way to track the download is after creating this link in Orangedox

The short answer is yes, you need to create a new share link within [Orangedox](http://dropbox.orangedox.com) and use that to share it with your audience; then you'll be able to view the number of times the file was downloaded using that share link.

Also note, unlike Dropbox you can create multiple share links to one file so you can track different channels where the file was downloaded from (eg one link for your website, one that you sent to a friend etc..)

Answer (score -2):

> I mean, is not possible to track the downloads made previously to the creation of this link, is it?

Yes

> I would have to create the link through Orangedox and only after that, I can track the downloads, isn't it?

Yes